# How to delete a custom view mode?

Tags: 7

I have a site that had display suite installed, but the custom view mode I'm trying to delete is not listed in the display suite admin page (admin/structure/ds/view_modes).

So I tried disabling/uninstalling all DS modules, and that didn't seem to help. I re-installed the module and confirmed the ds_view_modes table is indeed empty.

I know I can uncheck the checkbox to disable it for a given content type, but I want it gone completely so it doesn't cause confusion.

In the image, you can see the extra display is called "Classified Ad"

How can I accomplish this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the source code. It could be a module iis registering it via [`hook_entity_info_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_entity_info_alter/7.x).

Comment: Thanks @benjy that was exactly the way to track it down.